# How to change fixed numbers into ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors, range

I have a VBA code in which figures from 0 to 13 are selected (fixed), and from here a map will be provided with the corresponding color. But... I want to change this into a range per color. For example, I don't want having a "1" coupled to dark blue, a "2" coupled to light blue etc., but I want a range. Like: figures between 0 - 50 --> dark blue, 50 - 100 --> light blue etc.

In the VBA code below you can see that figures higher than 13 (intStateValue) are provided with another protocol. But there's no range in the code (For intState = 1 To rngStates.Rows.Count). How can I create ranges as described above (0 - 50, 50 - 100, 100 - 150 etc.)?

Hope anyone can help me on this one! Thanks in advance!!

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kleurgemeenten()
'
' Using the values from named range POSTCODEGEBIEDEN
' And the colours from named range KLEUREN
' re colour the map on sheet MainMap
'
Dim intState As Integer
Dim strStateName As String
Dim intStateValue As Integer
Dim intColourLookup As Integer
Dim rngStates As Range
Dim rngColours As Range

Set rngStates = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("GEMEENTE").RefersTo)
Set rngColours = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("KLEUREN").RefersTo)

    With Worksheets("MainMap")
    For intState = 1 To rngStates.Rows.Count
        strStateName = rngStates.Cells(intState, 1).Text
        intStateValue = rngStates.Cells(intState, 2).Value
        If intStateValue > 13 Then
            ' stripped
            With .Shapes(strStateName)
                intColourLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CInt(Left(CStr(intStateValue), 1)), Range("KLEUREN"), True)
                .Fill.Patterned msoPatternWideUpwardDiagonal
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
                intColourLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CInt(Right(CStr(intStateValue), 1)), Range("KLEUREN"), True)
                .Fill.BackColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
            End With
        Else
            ' single colour
            intColourLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(intStateValue, Range("KLEUREN"), True)
            With .Shapes(strStateName)
                .Fill.Solid
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
            End With
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it was even less complex... Here is the final answer! :-) -->

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kleurgemeenten()
'
' Using the values from named range POSTCODEGEBIEDEN
' And the colours from named range KLEUREN
' re colour the map on sheet MainMap
'
    Dim intState As Integer
    Dim strStateName As String
    Dim intStateValue As Long
    Dim intColourLookup As Integer
    Dim rngStates As Range
    Dim rngColours As Range
    Dim WS_Control As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set WS_Control = Worksheets("Control")

    Set rngStates = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("GEMEENTE").RefersTo)
    Set rngColours = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("KLEUREN").RefersTo)

    With Worksheets("MainMap")
        For intState = 1 To rngStates.Rows.Count
            strStateName = rngStates.Cells(intState, 1).Text
            intStateValue = rngStates.Cells(intState, 2).Value
            If intStateValue >= WS_Control.Range("E14").Value Then
                'if value is higher than last number of the defined range
                With .Shapes(strStateName)
                    .Fill.Solid
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = WS_Control.Cells(14, 6).Interior.Color
                End With
            Else
                'if value is inside the defined range
                'Loop through value ranges
                For i = 3 To 14
                    'if relavent range found
                    If intStateValue < WS_Control.Range("E" & i).Value Then
                        intColourLookup = i - 2  'Had to reduce 2 because name range "rngColours" is defined from "E2"
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i

                With .Shapes(strStateName)
                    .Fill.Solid
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I think this might help you.

You have add the code that creates the table I talk about in the comments

```
Option Explicit

Sub Kleurgemeenten()
'
' Using the values from named range POSTCODEGEBIEDEN
' And the colours from named range KLEUREN
' re colour the map on sheet MainMap
'
Dim intState As Integer
Dim strStateName As String
Dim intStateValue As Integer
Dim intColourLookup As Integer
Dim rngStates As Range
Dim rngColours As Range

Set rngStates = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("GEMEENTE").RefersTo)
Set rngColours = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("KLEUREN").RefersTo)

Dim colorTable(1 To 2, 1 To 13) As Long
' creaing the table

With Worksheets("MainMap")
    For intState = 1 To rngStates.Rows.Count
        strStateName = rngStates.Cells(intState, 1).Text
        intStateValue = rngStates.Cells(intState, 2).Value

        Dim colorNumber As Long, i As Long
        colorNumber = 14

        For i = 1 To 13
            If intStateValue >= colorTable(1, i) And intStateValue < colorTable(2, i) Then colorNumber = i
        Next i

        If colorNumber > 13 Then
            ' stripped
            With .Shapes(strStateName)
                intColourLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CInt(Left(CStr(colorNumber), 1)), Range("KLEUREN"), True)
                .Fill.Patterned msoPatternWideUpwardDiagonal
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
                intColourLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CInt(Right(CStr(colorNumber), 1)), Range("KLEUREN"), True)
                .Fill.BackColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
            End With
        Else
            ' single colour
            intColourLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(colorNumber, Range("KLEUREN"), True)
            With .Shapes(strStateName)
                .Fill.Solid
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
            End With
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume that you want the cell E2="0-1000", E3="1000-2000", etc. I would create a 13x2 matrix, where the first column is a column of extracted lower bounds and the second one is a column of extracted upper bounds. Then for every intState you loop over the rows of the table and check if intStateValue is between the bounds and if so assign the colorNumber accordingly. I will update the code of my previous answer.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And yes, that would be the perfect solution! Thank you in advance, also for your quick reply!!

Comment: Running the code right now with a 0 (or 1) for the first color (grey) in cell E2, and 1000 in cell E3, 2000 in cell E4 results in a grey map, despite the values in column B. Has this still something to do with the limit (when a value exceeds the 13, then get the striped 'version'? --> because this part can be left out, there's no need for this when the values are higher than 13)?

Comment: The colors in column F are assigned to the figures provided in column E. Simply replace the colors in F will change the outcome. The total number for rngStates is created by using the total set of municipals in column A: (Set rngStates = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("GEMEENTE").RefersTo) and the colors (var rngColours ) are set by the colors in column F (see also the name manager for "GEMEENTE" and "KLEUREN"): Set rngColours = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("KLEUREN").RefersTo).

Comment: I understand what the sub is doing. I want to find the reason why you only get the grey color as the output. When I use this code for creating  the colorTable matrix everything is perfectly fine
`    Dim j As Long`
`    For j = 1 To 13`
`        colorTable(1, j) = (j - 1) * 1000`
`        colorTable(2, j) = j * 1000`
`    Next j`

Comment: And did you only changed the figures in column E (originally 0 to 13) to random ranges (so E2 = 1000, E3 = 1500, E4=2000 etc.) besides the new VBA code?

Comment: No, I just created this table to test if the code works. You have to write the code that takes the values from the range and converts it to the matrix. If the range looks like this (E2=1000, E3=2000,...) then the first column has 0 in the first row and the range E2:E13 in the remaining rows and the second column is the range E2:E14. If the range in E2:E14 looks like "0-1000", "1000-2000" then you need some string processing.

Comment: OK, in that case no prob! Got to take a look again at the VBA and create the final code. Will let you know the outcome. THANKS!!